# Sender profile in Transactional API Event

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Transactional API Event journey that is already running.

I want to change the sender profile.

Because it's a Transactional API Event, I can't create a new version or change the sender profile from the settings.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

In the transactional send journey type, Marketing Cloud will let you select the send classification, not the sender profile.

The send classification will define the sender profile there. Therefore, to use another sender profile in the running Transactional API Event journey, I would:

- Pause the journey
- Modify the current transactional send classification with a new sender profile OR create a new transactional send classification with the sender profile I wish to have
- Select that transactional send classification in the email send
- Resume the journey

Reference: [Create a send classification](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_send_classification.htm&type=5)